# Audi Q5 2012 2.0l shaking and noise

Tags: tires, suspension, wheel-bearing, wear, wheel-balance

I have a 2012 Audi Q5. Recently soon as I reach 120kmh the car starts shaking like you can feel the steering wheel and the whole car shaking like its about to fall apart.

I took it to a mechanic he said my wheels are worn off so I out a brand new 4 Dunlop wheels still same issue.

Any ideas? I hear clanking noise when i dry steer even after alignment the car still leans to the right side if I let the steering wheel go.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Shaking at a particular speed could be caused by any (or all) of the following:

- Tires which are not balanced. While it is possible that a wheel (the metal thing on which the tire is mounted) could also be unbalanced, standard practice is to balance the tire-and-wheel combination at one time.
- Tires which are not round. A tire only slightly out-of-round can jump and vibrate. Such tires should be ground round (using a truing machine) or replaced.
- Worn joints or bushings in the car's suspension or steering. There are a lot of parts in these systems, and parts wear over time. The suspension and the steering must be carefully examined for wear and defects; this may require some disassembly, and is a job for an expert not a job for the new do-it-yourselfer. A worn joint or bushing or CV joint is also likely the source for the clanking noise you hear.

The car's "leaning to the right" (I assume you mean *pulling* to the right) could be caused by:

- improper alignment
- a worn tire or tires

Finally: the "clank" noise might be dangerous, as it might be the noise made by a worn part just before the worn part fractures. Depending upon where in the suspension or steering the worn part is located, such a fracture could result in the loss of steering control or the collapse of the car's suspension at one or more corners.

The car should be promptly assessed and repaired by a competent mechanic.